# 2 Microservices in same subnet AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, microservices, subnet

I have an AWS application that currently has 1 microservice. Back-end traffic goes through CloudFront distribution and load balancer to an EC2 autoscaling group with 2 subnets (A and B) across 2 availability zones.

I would now like to add another microservice and would like to know if the EC2 autoscaling group for the 2nd one should use the same subnets A and B or two new ones C and D?

Also would it use the same load balancer and would they be in the same VPC?

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should use the same subnets A and B or two new ones C and D?

Up to you and your requirements. They can use same or different subnets.

> Also would it use the same load balancer and would they be in the same VPC?

If you are using ALB, you can define new listener based on the hostname/domain of your second microservice. Create new target group for it and re-use existing ALB.

Comment: so I assume I just add a load balancer rule that product.domain.com goes to product service target group and account.domain.com goes to account service target group. Also will have to add another domain record for the load balancer for the 2nd subdomain

Comment: @Kris Yes. Just make sure that your second microservice uses same AZs as the ALB.

Comment: sounds like a plan. Will I still be able to reuse the same load balancer if I decide to use new subnets for the 2nd service (assuming they are in the same two AZs)

Comment: @Kris Yes. Same AZ and same VPC obviously.